# How do I append a new row in a list by adding to the item of the previous row in KnockoutJs

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

If I had a template in KnockoutJs which is a 'foreach' template, when I 'push' the next bit of data onto the observable array shown in a grid, how do I ensure the value of the column is the previous row + 1.

e.g. (simplified)

```
        Col1
Row 1   5     [ Add Button ]
Row 2   6   <-- auto populated (+1)
```

Model (simplified):

```
viewModel = {
   ...
   addRow: function() {                                                         
                this.Rows.push ({ Col1:0 }) 
  }
}
```

I somehow need to access the previous row and push that data + 1, but when I inspect viewModel.Rows, there is no count or indexer.  How do I access this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by binding your add button to an anonymous function that passes the current Col1 value.

Would be something like this:

```
<script id="itemsTmpl" type="text/html">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
        <td>
            <button data-bind="click: function() { viewModel.addItem(id); }">Add Item</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

With addItem function like this:

```
var viewModel = {
    items: ko.observableArray([{id: 1}]),
    addItem: function(previousId) {
        this.items.push({
            id: previousId + 1
        });
    }
};
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/6gETk/

This may not be exactly what you need for your app, but the technique should let you pass the necessary data to your bound function.

Comment: Thats great, the only problem is my button is in the footer of the table not each row and not in the template. I don't know how to bind the data from the last row into the footer so I can +1.  Any ideas?  Do I bind a footer template, or try to index into the data?

Comment: Is something like this sufficient: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Anzwj/.  So, addItem looks something like:     

addItem: function() {
        var lastId = this.items()[this.items().length-1].id;
        this.items.push({id: lastId+1});
    }